# Unable to skip Windows 10 login screen

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login-screen

I'd like to skip Windows 10's login screen.

Initially, **User A** was my only profile. Then, I made **User B**, and removed User A using the command prompt. **User A** no longer shows up in Windows, but when I login, I still see **User A** *and* **User B**, and trying to login as User A no longer works.

I have removed the corrupted User Profile, but still have the same issue of **User A** showing up.

I ran `netplwiz` and allowed auto sign in, but this does not work either.

I'd like to skip the login screen but assume this "corrupted" user profile is maybe preventing that? What exactly might be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? "*...any ideas.*" is rather unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @CharlieRB I may be interpreting it incorrectly but OP's question is "How do I skip the windows 10 login screen upon bootup?"

Comment: @RegisteredUser I kind of figured that too. My comment was to get the OP to clarify specifically what they are asking. We can assume, but we may be wrong.

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, Sorry, I am trying to skip the Windows 10 login screen, but the normal fix of using netplwiz does not seem to work.